# NFS troubles: showmount -e {server IP} doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, nmap

I'm having a number of troubles setting up an NFS mount on a Ubuntu server, and the main issue seems to be in making connection from the client (a Mac).

I can ping the server address fine.

Here is an NMAP result:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.x
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Not shown: 65525 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp    closed ftp
22/tcp    open   ssh
80/tcp    open   http
111/tcp   open   rpcbind
443/tcp   open   https
2049/tcp  open   nfs
3306/tcp  open   mysql
32765/tcp closed unknown
32766/tcp closed unknown
32767/tcp closed filenet-powsrm
```

On the server side, when I execute:

```
showmount -e
```

It returns:

```
Export list for xxxx:
/var/nfs 192.168.x.x/255.255.255.0
```

However, when I try, from the client side:

```
showmount -e {server ip}
```

It fails with the following message:

**showmount: Cannot retrieve info from host: 192.168.16.51: RPC failed:: RPC: Unable to send; errno = Bad file descriptor**

I have done the following config on the server:

**/etc/exports**
/var/nfs  192.168.x.x/255.255.255.0(ro,no_subtree_check)

**/etc/hosts.allow**
portmap:    192.168.x.x/255.255.255.0
lockd:      192.168.x.x/255.255.255.0
rquotad:    192.168.x.x/255.255.255.0
mountd:     192.168.x.x/255.255.255.0
statd:      192.168.x.x/255.255.255.0

Let me know if I need to add any more info and I will edit the question.

Comment: Are there any firewall rules present (or between) on the Mac or Ubuntu system? `showmount -e 192.168...` to a test ubuntu virtualbox virt via `vboxnet0` and no firewalls shows the export list.

Comment: I will check that out tomorrow. For now I will try to set it up on my home server, which won't be as restricted as the server in work.

Comment: Right, how can I find if there are any firewall rules that prevent the NFS mount? The port scan shows the required ports are open - would it still show them as open, even if other rules exist which prevent ACTUAL connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to thrig, it turns out the issue was with my ufw settings. I have since stopped those particular connections being dropped and the NFS stuff is working great now.